# How to add an altChunk element to a XWPFDocument using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I would like to add HTML as an altChunk to a DOCX file using Apache POI. I know that doc4jx can do this with a simpler API but for technical reasons I need to use Apache POI.

Using the CT classes to do low level stuff with the xml is a little tricky. I can create an altChunk with following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTBodyImpl;

public class AltChunkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        doc.createParagraph().createRun().setText("AltChunk below:");
        QName ALTCHUNK =  new QName ( "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" ,  "altChunk" ) ; 
        CTDocument1 ctDoc = doc.getDocument() ; 
        CTBodyImpl ctBody =  (CTBodyImpl) ctDoc. getBody(); 
        XmlComplexContentImpl xcci =  ( XmlComplexContentImpl ) ctBody.get_store().add_element_user(ALTCHUNK); 
        // what's need to now add "<b>Hello World!</b>"
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.docx"));
        doc.write(out);
    }
}
```

But how do I add the html content to 'xcci' it now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Office Open XML` for `Word` (`*.docx`) the `altChunk` provides a method for using pure `HTML` to describe document parts.

**Two important notes about `altChunk`:**

First: It is used only for importing content.  If you open the document using `Word` and save it, the newly saved document will not contain the alternative format content part, nor the altChunk markup that references it.  Word saves all imported content as default `Office Open XML` elements.

Second: Most applications except `Word` which are able reading `*.docx` too will **not** reading the `altChunk` content at all. For example `Libreoffice` or `OpenOffice` `Writer` will **not** reading the `altChunk` content as well as `apache poi` will **not** reading the `altChunk` content when opening a `*.docx` file.

**How is `altChunk` implemented in the `*.docx` `ZIP` file structure?**

There are `/word/*.html` files in the `*.docx` `ZIP` file. Those are referenced by Id in `/word/document.xml` as `<w:altChunk r:id="htmlDoc1"/>` for example. The relation between the Ids and the `/word/*.html` files are given in `/word/_rels/document.xml.rels` as `<Relationship Id="htmlDoc1" Target="htmlDoc1.html" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk"/>` for example.

So we need at first `POIXMLDocumentPart`s for the `/word/*.html` files and `POIXMLRelation`s for the relation between the Ids and the `/word/*.html` files. Following code provides that by having a wrapper class which extends POIXMLDocumentPart  for the  `/word/htmlDoc#.html` files in the *.docx ZIP archive. This also provides methods for manipulating the HTML. Also it provides a method for creating the `/word/htmlDoc#.html` files in the *.docx ZIP archive and creating relations to it.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordWithHTMLaltChunk {

 //a method for creating the htmlDoc /word/htmlDoc#.html in the *.docx ZIP archive  
 //String id will be htmlDoc#.
 private static MyXWPFHtmlDocument createHtmlDoc(XWPFDocument document, String id) throws Exception {
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = document.getPackage();
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/" + id + ".html");
  PackagePart part = oPCPackage.createPart(partName, "text/html");
  MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument = new MyXWPFHtmlDocument(part, id);
  document.addRelation(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getId(), new XWPFHtmlRelation(), myXWPFHtmlDocument);
  return myXWPFHtmlDocument;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument;

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Default paragraph followed by first HTML chunk.");

  myXWPFHtmlDocument = createHtmlDoc(document, "htmlDoc1");
  myXWPFHtmlDocument.setHtml(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getHtml().replace("<body></body>",
   "<body><p>Simple <b>HTML</b> <i>formatted</i> <u>text</u></p></body>"));
  document.getDocument().getBody().addNewAltChunk().setId(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getId());  

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Default paragraph followed by second HTML chunk.");

  myXWPFHtmlDocument = createHtmlDoc(document, "htmlDoc2");
  myXWPFHtmlDocument.setHtml(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getHtml().replace("<body></body>",
   "<body>" +
   "<table>"+
   "<caption>A table></caption>" +
   "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th></tr>" +
   "<tr><td>John Doe</td><td>2018-12-01</td><td>1,234.56</td></tr>" +
   "</table>" +
   "</body>"
   ));
  document.getDocument().getBody().addNewAltChunk().setId(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getId());  

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordWithHTMLaltChunk.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }

 //a wrapper class for the  htmlDoc /word/htmlDoc#.html in the *.docx ZIP archive
 //provides methods for manipulating the HTML
 //TODO: We should *not* using String methods for manipulating HTML!
 private static class MyXWPFHtmlDocument extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private String html;
  private String id;

  private MyXWPFHtmlDocument(PackagePart part, String id) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   this.html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><style></style><title>HTML import</title></head><body></body>";
   this.id = id;
  }

  private String getId() {
   return id;
  }

  private String getHtml() {
   return html;
  }

  private void setHtml(String html) {
   this.html = html;
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
   writer.write(html);
   writer.close();
   out.close();
  }

 }

 //the XWPFRelation for /word/htmlDoc#.html
 private final static class XWPFHtmlRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
  private XWPFHtmlRelation() {
   super(
    "text/html", 
    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk", 
    "/word/htmlDoc#.html");
  }
 }
}
```

Note: Because of using `altChunk` this code needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` as mentioned in [apache poi faq-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Result:

[image]

Comment: For those who manually edit docx file as ZIP, don't forget to add `<Default Extension="html" ContentType="text/html"/>` in `[Content_Types].xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Axel Richter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53568834/10371946), I replaced the call to CTBody.addNewAltChunk() with CTBodyImpl.get_store().add_element_user(QName) which eliminates the added 15MB dependency on [ooxml-schemas](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas). Since this is being used in a desktop app, we are trying to keep the app size as small as possible. In case it may be of help to anyone else:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLRelation;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePartName;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagingURIHelper;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.SimpleValue;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTBodyImpl;

public class AltChunkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        doc.createParagraph().createRun().setText("AltChunk below:");
        addHtml(doc,"chunk1","<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style></style><title></title></head><body><b>Hello World!</b></body></html>");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("test.docx"));
        doc.write(out);
    }

    static void addHtml(XWPFDocument doc, String id,String html) throws Exception {
        OPCPackage oPCPackage = doc.getPackage();
        PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/" + id + ".html");
        PackagePart part = oPCPackage.createPart(partName, "text/html");
        class HtmlRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
            private HtmlRelation() {
                super(  "text/html",
                        "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk",
                        "/word/htmlDoc#.html");
            }
        }
        class HtmlDocumentPart extends POIXMLDocumentPart {
            private HtmlDocumentPart(PackagePart part) throws Exception {
                super(part);
            }

            @Override
            protected void commit() throws IOException {
                try (OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream()) {
                    try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")) {
                        writer.write(html);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        HtmlDocumentPart documentPart = new HtmlDocumentPart(part);
        doc.addRelation(id, new HtmlRelation(), documentPart);
        CTBodyImpl b = (CTBodyImpl) doc.getDocument().getBody();
        QName ALTCHUNK = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", "altChunk");
        XmlComplexContentImpl altchunk = (XmlComplexContentImpl) b.get_store().add_element_user(ALTCHUNK);
        QName ID = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships", "id");
        SimpleValue target = (SimpleValue)altchunk.get_store().add_attribute_user(ID);
        target.setStringValue(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is ok in poi-ooxml 4.0.0, where the class POIXMLDocumentPart and POIXMLRelation are in the package org.apache.poi.ooxml.*

```
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLRelation;
```

But how we can use in poi-ooxml 3.9, where the class are little different and in the org.apache.poi.*

```
import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.POIXMLRelation;
```