# Convert AltChunks in docx using docx4j

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

I have some templates with tags and these tags are replaced with HTML. I could do that using Apache POI following @AxelRichter 's answer here:
[How to replace text(tag) with HTML in docx using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863126/how-to-replace-texttag-with-html-in-docx-using-apache-poi)

As I know, these AltChunks are converted to Word format, when file is opened in MS Word. But I need to convert them before opening it. I found out that docx4j can do that using convertAltChunks() method in MainDocumentPart.

So, what I have tried to do:

```
XWPFDocument templateDocx = //here everything is replaced and fine. 
//AltChunks are converted when opened in MS Word
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
templateDocx.write(os);
templateDocx.close();

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()); 

//Opening document processed by Apache POI using docx4j
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(is);
//Converting AltChunks
WordprocessingMLPackage pkgOut = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().convertAltChunks();
pkgOut.save(response.getOutputStream());
```

But, AltChunks are not converted. How can I do that? Are Apache POI and Docx4j not compatible? If so, how can I replace tags with HTML using docx4j, as I described here?: [How to replace text(tag) with HTML in docx using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863126/how-to-replace-texttag-with-html-in-docx-using-apache-poi)

**UPDATE:**

If I open my result docx with 7zip I have got this:
Sreenshots of root folder, word folder, document.xml and _rels/document.xml.rels
someText is id of my AltChunk
someText.html contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style></style><title>HTML import</title></head><body><p><strong>qwe</strong></p><p><strong><em>asd</em></strong></p><p><strong><em><u>zxc</u></em></strong></p><p style="text-align: center;"><strong><em><u>123</u></em></strong></p></body>
```

[image: root]

[image: word folder]

[image: document.xml]

[image: document.xml.rels]

Comment: Are your altChunks of type XHTML?  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/JaxbXmlPartAltChunkHost.java#L197 Do you have docx4j-importXHTML jar on your classpath?  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML

Comment: @JasonPlutext, can I check this opening docx with 7zip? Please see my update. Everywhere AltChunks are html. Do they need to be xhtml of what?

Comment: Looking at the code, the part name needs to be eg someText.xhtml, not .html.  And its content needs to be well formed xml.

Comment: @JasonPlutext, thank you! Changing format to helped me. Also my xhtml was not well formed.