# Keeping width and height of base 64 image while writing a html flux in Word with POI

Tags: java, html, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using poi (5.2.2) in a Java class to write html flux in Microsoft Word model document.

```
MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument = createHtmlDoc(document, "htmlDoc");
myXWPFHtmlDocument.setHtml(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getHtml().replace(
    "<body></body>", "<body>"+ StringHtmlFlux + "</body>"));
replaceIBodyElementWithAltChunk(document, "${content}", myXWPFHtmlDocument);
```

Note: `${content}` is a marker in the model document.

Everything is fine except for the syle of image in base 64.

For instance something like `<img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" src=\"C:/Temp/fleur.jpg\">`
kept the size defined by width and height attributes once written in Word.

But a `img` with the same image in base 64 does not keep the width and height once written in Word: `<img width=\"50\" height=\"50\" src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...\">`

Is there a way to keep the size defined with a base 64 image?

I tried to put a balise style, but no success.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. I suspect your `MyXWPFHtmlDocument ` is the one in one of my answers [using MyXWPFHtmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3915431%20MyXWPFHtmlDocument%20&searchOn=3). I suspect you are referring to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863126/how-to-replace-texttag-with-html-in-docx-using-apache-poi/53872268#53872268. I tried this having an image with source `data:image/png;base64...` and it works for me having the given size `...width=\"50\" height=\"50\"...`.

Comment: Yes ! I used your previous answer to set me up. Thanks about that  it helped me a lot. As for the current issue, any idea what might cause that?