# Apache POI docx: HTML as an altChunk

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

Good morning 
I would like to add HTML as an altChunk to a DOCX file using Apache POI. To do that I followed this stackoverflow answer

[How to add an altChunk element to a XWPFDocument using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564028/how-to-add-an-altchunk-element-to-a-xwpfdocument-using-apache-poi)

Everything works perfectly except for a problem with special character of my language (italian).
My case is the follow: I have an external html file. To import that I use the following code

```
byte[] inputBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("testo.html"));
String xhtml = new String(inputBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Then I generate the docx using the code provided in the stackoverflow answer. 
If I unzip the .docx under the "word" folder I have correctly the file "chunk1.html". 
If I open it the special caracter are reported correctly, for example

```
L'attività in oggetto è:
```

but when I opened the document in Word I see this

```
L'attivitÃ  in oggetto Ã¨:
```

Is there same Microsoft Configuration that I missed? 
Do I need to specify the character set when I create the chunk?

Comment: What is the encoding of the text in the HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft` seems to take `ANSI` as the default character encoding for `HTML` chunks in `Word`. That's annoying as the whole other world takes Unicode (`UTF-8`) as the default now.

So we need to set charset for the `HTML` explicitly. In the template of the chunk's `HTML` do:

```java
...
  private MyXWPFHtmlDocument(PackagePart part, String id) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   this.html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><style></style><title>HTML import</title></head><body></body>";
   this.id = id;
  }
...
```

I would recommend this instead of using `ANSI` encoding for the `HTML` chunks.

I have edited this into my answer in [How to add an altChunk element to a XWPFDocument using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564028/how-to-add-an-altchunk-element-to-a-xwpfdocument-using-apache-poi) too.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are very kind. It works perfectly.