# Is it possible to insert HTML at a specific position in a Word dokument using Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am trying to insert HTML text at a specific position in a ms Word-document using Apache POI.

I have been following the instruction that i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564028/how-to-add-an-altchunk-element-to-a-xwpfdocument-using-apache-poi) by [Yaun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10371946/yaun). It is a very good example, but only show how to add HTML last in the document. Is it because it´s not possible to insert it somewhere else or do someone know how to, and have the time to explain to me or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Fredrik

Comment: How are you going to identify the specific position? You need a bookmark, a paragraph number, or something else.

Comment: It´s not a problem for me to get the position of a bookmark, paragrap or a Run. My problem is that I don´t know/see how I do an insert of HTML to that position (or if it´s possible). All of the examples I find only shows how to put HTML last in a Word-document with for example this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577271/14233434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert something into a `XWPFDocument`' s body, one would need a `XmlCursor` which points to the inserting position. Same is done already in methods `XWPFDocument. insertNewParagraph(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor)` and `XWPFDocument.insertNewTbl(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor)`.

So we would need a method `insertAltChunk(XWPFDocument document, MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument, XmlCursor cursor)` to insert `altChunk` at position `cursor` of `document` pointing to `myXWPFHtmlDocument`'s `Id`.

```
...
 boolean isCursorInBody(XWPFDocument document, XmlCursor cursor) {
  XmlCursor verify = cursor.newCursor();
  verify.toParent();
  boolean result = (verify.getObject() == document.getDocument().getBody());
  verify.dispose();
  return result;
 }
 
 void insertAltChunk(XWPFDocument document, MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument, XmlCursor cursor) {
  if (isCursorInBody(document, cursor)) {
   QName ALTCHUNK = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", "altChunk");
   QName ID = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships", "id");
   cursor.beginElement(ALTCHUNK);
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue(ID, myXWPFHtmlDocument.getId());
   cursor.dispose();   
  }  
 }
...
```

Complete example, basing on my code in [How to add an altChunk element to a XWPFDocument using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564028/how-to-add-an-altchunk-element-to-a-xwpfdocument-using-apache-poi), which inserts `altChunk`s before second and fifth paragraph in existing `Word` document.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class InsertHTMLaltChunkInWordAtCursor {

 //a method for creating the htmlDoc /word/htmlDoc#.html in the *.docx ZIP archive  
 //String id will be htmlDoc#.
 private static MyXWPFHtmlDocument createHtmlDoc(XWPFDocument document, String id) throws Exception {
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = document.getPackage();
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/" + id + ".html");
  PackagePart part = oPCPackage.createPart(partName, "text/html");
  MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument = new MyXWPFHtmlDocument(part, id);
  document.addRelation(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getId(), new XWPFHtmlRelation(), myXWPFHtmlDocument);
  return myXWPFHtmlDocument;
 }
 
 private static boolean isCursorInBody(XWPFDocument document, XmlCursor cursor) {
  XmlCursor verify = cursor.newCursor();
  verify.toParent();
  boolean result = (verify.getObject() == document.getDocument().getBody());
  verify.dispose();
  return result;
 }
 
 private static void insertAltChunk(XWPFDocument document, MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument, XmlCursor cursor) {
  if (isCursorInBody(document, cursor)) {
   QName ALTCHUNK = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", "altChunk");
   QName ID = new QName("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships", "id");
   cursor.beginElement(ALTCHUNK);
   cursor.insertAttributeWithValue(ID, myXWPFHtmlDocument.getId());
   cursor.dispose();   
  }  
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("./WordDocument.docx"));
  
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;

  MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument;

  myXWPFHtmlDocument = createHtmlDoc(document, "htmlDoc1");
  myXWPFHtmlDocument.setHtml(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getHtml().replace("<body></body>",
   "<body><p>Simple <b>HTML</b> <i>formatted</i> <u>text</u></p></body>"));
  paragraph = document.getParagraphArray(1);
  XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
  insertAltChunk(document, myXWPFHtmlDocument, cursor);
  
  myXWPFHtmlDocument = createHtmlDoc(document, "htmlDoc2");
  myXWPFHtmlDocument.setHtml(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getHtml().replace("<body></body>",
   "<body>" +
   "<table border=\"1\">"+
   "<caption>A table</caption>" +
   "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th></tr>" +
   "<tr><td>John Doe</td><td>2018-12-01</td><td>1,234.56</td></tr>" +
   "</table>" +
   "</body>"
   ));
  paragraph = document.getParagraphArray(4);
  cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
  insertAltChunk(document, myXWPFHtmlDocument, cursor);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("InsertHTMLaltChunkInWordAtCursor.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }

 //a wrapper class for the  htmlDoc /word/htmlDoc#.html in the *.docx ZIP archive
 //provides methods for manipulating the HTML
 //TODO: We should *not* using String methods for manipulating HTML!
 private static class MyXWPFHtmlDocument extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private String html;
  private String id;

  private MyXWPFHtmlDocument(PackagePart part, String id) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   this.html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><style></style><title>HTML import</title></head><body></body>";
   this.id = id;
  }

  private String getId() {
   return id;
  }

  private String getHtml() {
   return html;
  }

  private void setHtml(String html) {
   this.html = html;
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
   writer.write(html);
   writer.close();
   out.close();
  }

 }

 //the XWPFRelation for /word/htmlDoc#.html
 private final static class XWPFHtmlRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
  private XWPFHtmlRelation() {
   super(
    "text/html", 
    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk", 
    "/word/htmlDoc#.html");
  }
 }
}
```

See also [How to replace text(tag) with HTML in docx using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863126/how-to-replace-texttag-with-html-in-docx-using-apache-poi/53872268#53872268).