# Embedding Images Directly into OOXML Content Without Using Relationships

Tags: apache-poi, openxml

In Microsoft Word's OOXML format, images are typically stored in the word/media folder and referenced in the document XML through relationships, as shown in this snippet:

```
<w:drawing>
    <!-- ... other tags ... -->
    <pic:blipFill>
        <a:blip r:embed="rId8577" cstate="none"/>
        <!-- ... other tags ... -->
    </pic:blipFill>
    <!-- ... other tags ... -->
</w:drawing>
```

In this structure, rId8577 references an image located in the word/media directory.

Is there a way to embed the image content directly into the OOXML file, instead of referencing it from an external file?

I'm aware that embedding images as base64-encoded data directly in the XML is possible in formats like HTML or SVG, but I'm not sure if this approach is compatible or recommended for OOXML.

Any insights or alternative suggestions for including images directly within the OOXML structure would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, embedding Images as base64-encoded data directly in the XML is not recommended for OOXML.

As it is possible in HTML it could be done using HTML using that HTML in alternate chunk `altChunk` elements. See my answers https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3915431%20MyXWPFHtmlDocument&searchOn=3 for examples. Please read carefully [How to add an altChunk element to a XWPFDocument using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564028/how-to-add-an-altchunk-element-to-a-xwpfdocument-using-apache-poi/53568834#53568834) about disadvantages.

Following example shows hot to embed `<img src=\"data:image/png;base64, ... />` into such alternate-chunk-HTML.

```java
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordWithHTMLaltChunk {

 //a method for creating the htmlDoc /word/htmlDoc#.html in the *.docx ZIP archive  
 //String id will be htmlDoc#.
 private static MyXWPFHtmlDocument createHtmlDoc(XWPFDocument document, String id) throws Exception {
  OPCPackage oPCPackage = document.getPackage();
  PackagePartName partName = PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/word/" + id + ".html");
  PackagePart part = oPCPackage.createPart(partName, "text/html");
  MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument = new MyXWPFHtmlDocument(part, id);
  document.addRelation(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getId(), new XWPFHtmlRelation(), myXWPFHtmlDocument);
  return myXWPFHtmlDocument;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  MyXWPFHtmlDocument myXWPFHtmlDocument;

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Default paragraph followed by HTML chunk.");

  myXWPFHtmlDocument = createHtmlDoc(document, "htmlDoc1");
  myXWPFHtmlDocument.setHtml(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getHtml().replace("<body></body>",
   "<body>" +
   "<table>"+
   "<caption>Person</caption>" +
   "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Photo</th></tr>" +
   "<tr><td>John Doe</td>" +
   "<td>" +
   "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,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\" />" +
   "</td></tr>" +
   "</table>"+
   "</body>"
   ));
  document.getDocument().getBody().addNewAltChunk().setId(myXWPFHtmlDocument.getId());  

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordWithHTMLaltChunk.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }

 //a wrapper class for the  htmlDoc /word/htmlDoc#.html in the *.docx ZIP archive
 //provides methods for manipulating the HTML
 //TODO: We should *not* using String methods for manipulating HTML!
 private static class MyXWPFHtmlDocument extends POIXMLDocumentPart {

  private String html;
  private String id;

  private MyXWPFHtmlDocument(PackagePart part, String id) throws Exception {
   super(part);
   this.html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><style></style><title>HTML import</title></head><body></body>";
   this.id = id;
  }

  private String getId() {
   return id;
  }

  private String getHtml() {
   return html;
  }

  private void setHtml(String html) {
   this.html = html;
  }

  @Override
  protected void commit() throws IOException {
   PackagePart part = getPackagePart();
   OutputStream out = part.getOutputStream();
   Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
   writer.write(html);
   writer.close();
   out.close();
  }

 }

 //the XWPFRelation for /word/htmlDoc#.html
 private final static class XWPFHtmlRelation extends POIXMLRelation {
  private XWPFHtmlRelation() {
   super(
    "text/html", 
    "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/aFChunk", 
    "/word/htmlDoc#.html");
  }
 }
}
```

---

Since you mentioned SVG, another possibility would be using [VML](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML#_Toc416858380) paths to describe the image.

Complete Example for this too:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPicture;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR;

import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTGroup;
import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTShape;
import com.microsoft.schemas.vml.CTPath;
import com.microsoft.schemas.office.word.STWrapType;

import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class CreateWordVMLShape {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body text: ");

  CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();

  CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
  ctShape.addNewWrap().setType(STWrapType.SQUARE);
  ctShape.setStyle("position:absolute;mso-position-horizontal:center;margin-top:40pt;width:50pt;height:50pt;");
  ctShape.setFillcolor("#FF0000");
  ctShape.setCoordsize("175, 175");
  CTPath ctPath = ctShape.addNewPath();
  ctPath.setV​("m 8,65 l 72,65,92,11,112,65,174,65,122,100,142,155,92,121,42,155,60,100 x e");
  
  Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
  CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  CTR cTR = run.getCTR();
  cTR.addNewPict();
  cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... Lorem ipsum semit color ... ");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./WordVMLShape.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```